# Build a directed regular graph of elements in an array

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph-theory

Given an array, I would like to be able to define some relationship between its elements so that each element "points to" a given number of elements, such that no element should share more than one target element with any other given element of the array.

I'm pretty sure this can be done easily with some solution from graph theory, but I embarrassingly don't know any graph theory and therefore don't know what I'm looking for. The best I can say is that the graph describing the links between elements is regular and directed.

The XY: what I actually have/want is two-dimensional grid (I don't think the dimension is relevant to the math but is very helpful with the visualization), where each cell points to *around* 16 (flexible on this) other cells with a minimum of duplication. The grid is a texture so it's anywhere in the 256*256 to 4096*4096 size range, which hopefully doesn't make a significant difference to the algorithm.

Once visualized as a 2D texture, there is an obvious "intuitive" solution based on image masks, but it's totally informal and relies on the implementation details (using fewer targets for the purposes of illustration):

1. Using a regular pattern for the pointed-to cells is inappropriate:

   [image: Imgur]

   The next cell along will share *seven* targets with the origin cell (red, x). Duplication is guaranteed.
2. An irregular "broken circle" style arrangement intuitively seems like it should work:

   [image: Imgur]

   If no pair of cells in the group (pointed-to and origin) have an equal difference in position to any other pair of cells in the group, then any given movement of the origin on the grid seems like it shouldn't result in more than one pointed-to cell overlapping with any of those highlighted in the original position, and none of the pointed-to (blue) cells should point back to the origin (red, x) directly (it would be nice if they didn't loop back too quickly, either).

("wrapping around" at the edges of the texture is assumed)

But this is totally informal and intuitive. I don't have any proof of this and don't know how to go about proving it. Is there an algorithm known from graph theory that can produce such a result, without wishy-washy handwaving involving image masks? Not least because the intuitive solution, even assuming it works, doesn't provide any guarantees about whether the target cells will loop back to the origin quickly or not, and whether the entire grid (or most of it, I don't mind a few unused cells) forms a single connected graph, which is absolutely essential.

Alternatively, if the "broken circle" model actually works, how would one go about formalizing this back down to an abstract algorithm operating on a sequence (I guess it's effectively just an integer sequence), rather than relying on a mask image, which is totally getting confused by implementation details? (The fact that I want to apply this *to* a texture should be irrelevant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mathematical description of what you want to do is to build a (strongly?) connected high-[girth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girth_%28graph_theory%29) [Cayley graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph) on the group **Z**/w × **Z**/h (where w is the width of the texture and h is the height) such that no two vertices have more than one out-neighbor in common.

Practically speaking, each vertex (i.e., pixel) points to the pixels at a fixed list of offsets. If a vertex at (0, 0) (w.l.o.g. by the vertex-transitivity of Cayley graphs) and a vertex at (x, y) have two out-neighbors in common, then there exist offsets (dx1, dy1), (dx2, dy2), (dx3, dy3), (dx4, dy4) such that (dx1, dy1) = (x + dx2, y + dy2) and (dx3, dy3) = (x + dx4, y + dy4), and (dx1, dy1) ≠ (dx3, dy3) (equivalently, (dx2, dy2) ≠ (dx4, dy4)). This condition can be verified programmatically, and for random sets of offsets within a close distance, it doesn't take long to find a suitable set. Here's some Python to generate and test them.

```
from random import randrange

# random pattern of offsets within the square [-k, k] x [-k, k]
def pattern(k, n):
    return [(randrange(-k, k + 1), randrange(-k, k + 1)) for i in range(n)]

def valid(pat):
    s = set()
    for (x1, y1) in pat:
        for (x2, y2) in pat:
            if ((x1, y1) != (x2, y2)):
                (dx, dy) = (x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
                if (dx, dy) in s:
                    return False
                s.add((dx, dy))
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        pat = pattern(10, 16)
        if valid(pat):
            break
    print(pat)
```

This code does not verify strong connectivity. I would conjecture that strong connectivity is very likely to be satisfied by random offset sets. You might want to write more code to check for short cycles, which can be found by breadth-first search.

The code above gives a list of offsets like

```
[(3, -4), (-8, -9), (2, 7), (-9, 3), (-4, 7), (-2, -7), (-6, 3), (-7, -2), (9, -10), (8, -2), (-6, -3), (2, -8), (-6, 6), (-9, -7), (-7, 10), (3, 10)]
```

(no idea if that one's any good). To figure out which vertices (x, y) points to, iterate (dx, dy) through the list above and yield the neighbor ((x + dx) & (w - 1), (y + dy) & (h - 1)), assuming that w and h are powers of two and that we're two's complement.